# Maintain the aspect ratio of an image that is within a circle

Tags: css

I am trying to make basic CSS challenges. In this case I have an image that I have given a circle, but I do not know what to do so that it retains its aspect ratio, does not fully cover the entire circle and is centered. This is the code I have. I want to learn a way to achieve this effect with any image of any resolution.

Desired effect:

[image]

```css
img{
  border-radius:50%;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.image_container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_container">
    <img src="https://danikalaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/r.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the sizing condition on the container rather than the image.

```css
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.image_container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_container">
    <img src="https://danikalaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/r.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `CSS` on `img` that should be on `.image-container`. Then, you can set `width` for `image` enough to be centered and not override the circle, like this:

```
.image_container {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
img {
  width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
}

.image_container {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px; height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_container">
    <img src="https://danikalaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/r.png">
</div>
```

Comment: To keep the padding/border in check, basically you could also just reduce the size of the image like @Azametzin is suggesting, but I prefer to use padding. Without `border-box` the padding and border are added to the dimensions of the element, e.g. in this case the total width of the image would become 360x360px, with `border-box` it stays 300x300px and will instead reduce the images size.

Answer (score 0):

#### Outline

- Wrap **`<img>`** tag in a block level tag and then wrap that tag with another block level tag:

  ```
  <section class="frame">
    <figure class="logo">
      <img class="image">
    ...
  ```
- Assign the top ancestor tag (**demo.** `section.frame`)

  ```
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  ```

  Basic CSS positioning -- parent is `relative` -- child is `absolute` -- child references its `relative` parent's area for X, Y position. The value: `50vw` is equivalent to 50% of viewport width. This makes the tag responsive and it will dynamically change it's dimensions and maintain aspect ratio whenever the viewport width changes.
- Assign the parent tag of `<img>` tag (**demo.** `figure.logo`)

  ```
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  ```

  This positions it to the edges of **`section.frame`**.
- Assign the **`<img>`** the following:

  ```
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  ```

  This will position **`img.image`** to the edges of **`figure.logo`**

Added a `:hover` effect to show how the img tag fits within the figure and section tags. Each tag is assigned `border-radius: 50%` so that there are no square corners overlapping the visible border on `section.frame`.

```css
.frame {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  border: 3px solid #B9BBC0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.frame:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<section class='frame'>
  <figure class='logo'>
    <img class='image' src='https://danikalaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/r.png'>
  </figure>
</section>
```

**References**
[**`Viewport CCS Concepts`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Viewport_concepts#CSS)
[**`object-fit: contain`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property
[**`position`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) property